# How to add onKeyUp()/onKeyDown() to an activity/view that I do not create?

Tags: android, events, marmalade, ouya

I need to add `onKeyUp()`/`onKeyDown()` event handling to my application, in which I did not create the `Activity` and main `View`. (Getting `OuyaController` working with a Marmalade SDK application).

With `onGenericMotion()` it seems straightforward (`view.setOnGenericMotionListener()`), however I'm confused about `view.setOnKeyListener()`, as the interface of the `android.View.OnKeyListener` that it takes as an argument has a single `onKey()` method, and not `onKeyUp()`/`onKeyDown()`.

Apparently, `view.KeyEvent.Callback` has this interface, which `Activity` and `View` implement - what class has this interface and how can I add its functionality to a `View` procedurally?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can add any method or event handling in any activity which you didn't create. The best possible solution would be to subclass the Activity, add your modification and use that class instead.

Answer (score 0):

The onKey method will pass you a KeyEvent. Check getAction() for ACTION_UP, ACTION_DOWN and ACTION_MULTIPLE states.